# Labels collide on axis crossing in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I faced an issue while using axis crossing with Excel. In this i have moved the x and y axis line with the labels as like in the below screenshot.

[image: Excel Image]

Here the axis line has collided with the axis labels as highlighted in yellow colored. So, kindly suggest me a way to over come this in Excel.

Thanks in advance,
Dharani.

Comment: Disable axis labeling would solve this.

Comment: Thanks @Luuklag, but i need to have axis labels with axis crossing, is there any other solution to move the particular labels which collides with axis line?

Comment: Let axis intersect in between labels, so on (3.25),(3.25)